# How do you say "anything is possible" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

If you wanted to say that anything is possible in Latin, how would you do it?

One possibility I thought of was something like:

> Omne posse

I'm not sure that *omne* quite captures the nuance of *anything* versus *everything*. In other words, the original in English is saying *any* of these things is possible, but not all of them. It's splitting hairs, really, but is there a more idiomatic way to say this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit how you ended up with the infinitive *posse*?

Comment: Poor life choices... No, in all seriousness, I was looking at the idiom example from the entry for [possum](http://archives.nd.edu/cgi-bin/wordz.pl?keyword=posse) in Whitaker's Words and he gave the example _multum posse_, so I modeled it after that.

Comment: In that entry, *posse* is in the infinitive state for dictionary purposes. It is set apart from actual uses. So you would have something like, "Caesar multum potest" --> "Caesar has much influence/power."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to express that would be:

> *Omnia possibilia sunt*.
>
> All things are possible.

This actually comes from the Vulgate, where Jesus said:

> *Apud homines hoc inpossibile est,*
> *apud Deum autem omnia possibilia sunt*. (Mateus 19:26)
>
> With men this is impossible; with God, however,
> all things are possible.

**Everything vs. anything:**

Concerning your comment about whether *anything* and *everthing* can be interchanged, I believe it's common for translators to do so. Technically, it doesn't express the idea in the exact same way. Rather, it's considering the same thing from different pespectives: *everthing* considers the subject collectively, whereas *anything* considers it from an individual point of view (i.e. each thing considered in turn). Even so, I believe it's often important for the translator to express thing in a way that seems natural.